# Foreman on Centos 7: how to list hosts with Package X installed

Tags: centos7, foreman, satellite

We tried very hard to install and love Spacewalk without success. So we moved to Satellite 6, which on Centos 7 is the Foreman/Katello/Pulp/Candlepin combo.

It's all set up fine, and we are using it to deploy, update and install packages.

One thing I can't find is how to get a list of hosts which have package X installed. (in this case, postgresql-server)

Is it possible and I'm just not finding it, or am I asking too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this information under Hosts > Content hosts, then write in the search field:

"installed_package_name = postgresql-server"

Comment: Can you also query by package_version?

Comment: ```installed_package =  sudo-1.8.19p2-13.el7.x86_64```

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same issue cannot find packages installed on CentOS servers. I was able to add hosts on foreman server using setup playbook. My environment has ansible plug-in and on foreman server. No Katello on foreman.